# Как сравнить значение введенное с клавиатуры Android с переменной?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Когда пытаюсь сравнить значение введенное с клавиатуры , со значением переменной ничего не происходит.

Код:

```
 Double rus;
 Double las=32;
 Entry name = new Entry
        {

            //Label = "Баллы:",
            Placeholder = "введите баллы",
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric,

        };
    rus= Convert.ToDouble(name.Text);

private void Dobavit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button dobavit = (Button)sender;
        if (rus==las) 
        { dobavit.Text = "сработало!";


        dobavit.BackgroundColor = Color.DarkBlue; }

    }
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что сдесь  Button dичегонobavit = (Button)sender; всё правильно?

Comment: В коде написано  (Button)sende ?

Comment: Лучше сразу вопрос исправьте если там ошибка.

Comment: поищите рядом с вопросом, там должен быть пункт редактировать вопрос (или что-то в этом роде)

Comment: всё я исправил.)

Comment: правда все равно ничего не работает . не хочет выполнять условия

Comment: Не за что. В с# не разбираюсь не смогу помочь.

Comment: Перенесите `rus= Convert.ToDouble(name.Text);` внутрь метода `Dobavit_Clicked`. Сейчас вы непонятно в какой момент пытаетесь прочитать текст из поля name. И там в этот момент скорее всего пусто.

Comment: ошибка когда перенес: Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>